# Scroll table's frozen column vertically

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, frozen-columns

I have this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/5484/) and I want to scroll the frozen column vertically without using JavaScript or modify the `html` code (I can add more containers, bot other things I don't want to change). Is it possible?

```css
body { font:16px Calibri;}
table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
td {
   margin:0;
   border:3px solid grey; 
   border-top-width:0px; 
   white-space:nowrap;
}
div { 
   width: 600px; 
   overflow-x:scroll;  
   margin-left:5em; 
   overflow-y:visible;
   padding-bottom:1px;
   height: 200px;
}
.headcol {
   position:absolute; 
   width:5em; 
   left:0;
   top:auto;
   border-right: 0px none black; 
   border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
   margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
}
.headcol:before {content: 'Row ';}
.long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }
```

```html
<div><table>
        <tr><td class="headcol">1</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">2</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">3</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">4</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">5</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">6</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">7</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">8</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">9</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">10</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">11</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">12</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">13</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">14</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to have a fixed column AND be able to scroll in poth directions with purely CSS and HTML. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23503250/1434964) answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand good, you want to scroll everything.
 If so, you have to remove absolute positioning in a `.headcol` class
It means remove `absolute`, `top` and `left` from css

To move it back to position, remove `margin-left:5em;` from `div` element in css

Comment: Horizontally I don't want to move the first column